# Кеширование в codeigniter

Tags: кэширование, codeigniter, php

Частенько делаю проекты на Codeigniter(далее CI) скорости хватало с головой.Ci во много раз шустрее Zend(но там не плохой кеш) , так что юзать кеш не приходилось. Но тут такое дело вышло что делаю довольно крупный проект на нем и думаю что не помешало бы настроить кеш, кешеривоние БД вещь хорошая но мне кажется не эффективная что касаеться $this->output->cach тоже не очень так как оно кеширует страницу целиком а на ней может меняться некоторые блоки типа авторизации и имени пользователя. Народ подскажите кто каким кешированием пользуется в данном фреймворке.

сделал как то так

```
$key = md5(serialize($this->data));
      if ($cache = $this->cache->file->get($key))
      {
          echo  $cache;  
      }
      else
      {
        $per = 6;
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/page-';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->mod_art->get_count_index();
        $config['per_page'] = $per;
        $config['cur_page'] = $first;
        $config['end_slash'] = '';
        $config['first_url'] = base_url();
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_link'] = lang('last');
        $config['first_link'] = lang('first');
        $config['next_link'] = '<img src="/images/arrow_next.png" width="17" height="12" alt="'.lang('next').'" title="'.lang('next').'">';
        $config['prev_link'] = '<img src="/images/arrow_prev.png" width="17" height="12" alt="'.lang('prev').'" title="'.lang('prev').'">';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $this->data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->data['articles'] = $this->mod_art->get_index($first,$per);
        $this->data['content'] = $this->templete('main/index',true);
        $cache_tmp = $this->templete('main',true);
                $this->cache->file->save($key,$cache_tmp,300);
                echo $cache_tmp;
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Скачай с github последнюю версию - 3.0-dev

Там теперь много драйверов для кэширования

Comment: Извините но скачать что?

Comment: уже понял что CI 3.0 dev  а чем она отличаеться?!

Comment: там немало новых возможностей, например теперь CI поддерживает кеширование: APC, Dummy, File, Memcached, Redis, Wincache.

Comment: Разберитесь как работает например memcached, потом поймете как очень просто его в CI использовать.

Comment: memcached разобрал

Comment: Можете поделиться примером...

Comment: Давайте в скайпе ukroficer

Comment: @ukroficer, а давайте здесь! Ваш опыт может еще кому-нибудь пригодиться.