# CodeIgniter: Кеширование

Tags: кэширование, php, auth, codeigniter, mysql

В общем у меня назрел такой вопрос, у меня предположим есть сайт с авторизацией пользователей, и я внезапно захотел включить кеширование, как правильнее будет сделать игнорирование кеширования на предположим

```
<div id="#auth"> Привет {login} </div>
```

... может у вас есть какие идеи и предложения ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем у меня назрел ответ.

Предположим у тебя есть сайт, ты включил кеширование.

зачем кешировать то, что не должно попадать в кеш?

Кешировать можно переменные, куски кода html, всю страницу, вариантом то куча.

что нужно в кеш, что нет так зачем кешировать тогда.

```
if ( ! $end = $this->cache->load('name_ceche') ) {
    $blog = $this->db->get(«blog»);
    $data['content'] = $blog->result();
    $end = $this->load->view('myfile', $data, true);
    $this->cache->save($end, 'name_ceche', array('page1', 'blog'));
}
```

[тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/165075/php-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-codeigniter) глянь

Comment: ну так у меня тонны кода) где надо не кешировать только определенный блок.

Comment: так не кешируй его и все, в чем проблема то?

Comment: в том что мне пока лень смотреть про memchache и я в данном случае рассматриваю 

" $this->output->cache(n); "

Comment: ну раз лень, тогда ответ **НИКАК**!

в YII круче реализовано кеширование.

Answer (score 0):

Я уникально кеширую так в главном контролере (у меня это это Public_controller) я создаю масив unique дальше в него кидаю уникальное например имя или id авторизировавшегося а потом не посредственно в контролере проверяю строку кеширования так $str_cache = md5(current_url() . $this->_unique);